# Event Manager: Events Deleted are still in DB as published but hidden in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, database

I have a plugin called events manager. There are 400+ events imported. I noticed when I removed a few we didn't wish to include, they were removed from the admin menu, but they still show in site search. After digging more, they are still in the DB as Published. By URLjacking the edit.php? query string, I am able to navigate to these posts and update them, this causes them to show back in the admin again. Has anyone seen this? Is there a reason why a custom post might become corrupt and you cannot access it via the admin?

Comment: This probably has more to do with `pre_get_posts` and the events manager plugin, is this a plugin you wrote yourself or a 3rd party plugin?

Comment: It is a third party plugin. To debug, I have just started walking the code, removing anything unnecessary from the class-wp-posts-lists-table.php to see if a meta query was filtering these posts out, maybe due to some bad tax, meta, or other, that might orphan these posts.